# Unwind segue working incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I am trying to perform an unwind segue. I've successfully created the unwind segue but the problem is that when it is triggered, it continues past the destination ViewController that contains the @IBAction function that is supposed to stop the unwinding. [image]

This is what my storyboard looks like. When I'm unwinding I am on the Third Test View Controller. The @IBAction function for the unwind is in ResearchTestController (that's my desired destination). When the unwind is triggered, it unwinds down to the destination but then some how instances of the Third Test View Controller and the Second Test View Controller are added on top of the ResearchTestController. Here is a before and after screenshot of the view hierarchy.

Before (before I start the unwind while in the Third Test View Controller):
[image]

After (after the unwind):
[image]

The segues that go from ViewController to ViewController are Show(push) as well. If anyone has any insight as to how to solve this problem I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your storyboard suggests that either this is not an unwind segue or you've got an extra undesired segue. There's a push segue leading from FirstTestViewController to ResearchTestController. That's wrong. You've got a potential infinite cycle of push segues, since it is possible to start at ResearchTestController and then push a FirstTestViewController and then push a *second* ResearchTestController and so forth. That may be the cause of the issue you're having.

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt. After deleting that push segue going from First Test View Controller to ResearchTestController, the same problem still exists. Another thing I'll add is that when I segue, I do it programmatically as opposed to the segues being tied to a button. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Well, only to the extent that I've no idea what you're doing because you've chosen to conceal just about everything of relevance (i.e. you've shown no code whatever). Your screen shots are not particularly illuminating (and are unnecessarily huge). If you can reproduce the issue in a minimal complete verifiable example, then describe it or, even better, post it on github and I'll look at it.

Comment: Your suggestion to create a sample project made me figure out the problem. So I thank you for the responses despite the huge/not useful pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out the solution to the problem. To move from one ViewController to the next I would segue programmatically in the viewDidAppear method. When you perform an unwind segue, as the app is unwinding, it hits the viewDidAppear method of every ViewController it finds in the stack. So in my case it was executing extra segues as it was moving through the stack of ViewControllers. Thus causing the views piled on top of each other. Once I added the appropriate checks to make sure that didn't happen I solved the problem.

Comment: That's great, but there was no way for us to know it from the question. The question/answer pair is thus a bad one. I recommend deleting the question (though of course the choice is yours).